# Mockito-core with pitest

Tags: gradle, mockito, pitest

I have to upgrade dependencies for a module and I use pitest version 1.7.4.

When I update the mockito-core version to 4.5.0 all my tests from pitest fail with message "did not pass wihout mutation". With mockito-core 4.0.0 everything works fine.

Also, if I try to update to 4.1.0 still the same. The logging from pitest is not really helping me, I looked up to release notes for mockito-core (https://github.com/mockito/mockito/releases?page=2) but I dont have any ideas.

Did someone encounter this too?

Comment: 1.7.4 is quite an old version of pitest, the latest is 1.9.5. Can you provide an example of a test that fails when upgraded? Pitest's own test suite passes when upgraded to 4.5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the following: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/1112
I resolved this by replacing testImplementation("org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.9") with testImplementation("org.powermock:powermock-api-support:2.0.9")